# session to another client or server in domain with " name " is ok but not by " ip "

Tags: active-directory

Our **Primary Domain Controller** physically failed and now is **off** . Then I had to **seize FSMO rolls** to **additional DC** in our Domain .All needed rolls seized successfully ( netdom query shows the succession ) . 
but now I can not get session to the shared folders on servers or any client in domain by **ip** ( \ client-or-server-ip  )and the message " **the trust relationship between this workstation and primary domain controller failed** " is shown . plus I **have not any problem** in Login to servers or clients and remote desktop is ok plus take session with name of server or client is ok **but ip is not working** and the mentioned message above is given . Can any body help ???

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Reset-ComputerMachinePassword cmdlet.
It may be a computer cache credential giving you a problem here.

[Domain Trust and Powershell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1993437-domain-trust-and-powershell)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't worked too .